# Why is my watch getting disconnected from the phone sporadically

Tags: samsung, bluetooth, samsung-galaxy-note, smartwatch

I have a Samsung Note 20 Phone and a Samsung Watch 46mm.

I have it set up so that the watch vibrates if it loses connection with the phone. This happens about 4 times a day, even when I have both in my possession. I havent been bothered by it.

Unfortunately, this also happens when I  am sleeping.  It ignores the **Do Not Disturb** and wakes me at all sorts of hours. Normally I  ignore it and try to go back to sleep. I  finally looked at it at 4amish. Its losing connection.

I dont have any automation type software installed, so nothing should be fiddling with bluetooth.
**Why would the watch lose bluetooth connection with the phone ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an undesired partial solution.  My touch screen on the phone stopped working, but the stylus still did.  I took it to the retailer.  The first thing he did (without asking me) was **reset the settings**.  This did not fix the screen and I have to take it back for repair next week.

For those that are unaware of this feature as I was

1. Got **Settings** by clicking on the gear icon
2. Scroll down to **About Phone** and select it
3. Scroll down and select **Reset**
4. There are 4 items here

   1. Reset all settings
   2. Reset Network settings
   3. Reset accessibility settings
   4. Factory data reset

OR just search for **Reset** in **Settings**

Because of this, most apps lost most of their settings.  Now my watch was getting disconnected 10 minutes later.

I suspected that it may be Expressvpn.  Before the above incident, I used to have it Enabled by default.  Now I have turned off that option.  When I google it, there isn't any correlation between **ExpressVpn** and **Bluetooth**. But I still suspect it.  The good news is that my problem has disappeared.